# How to force diffstat to always show number of inserts, deletes and modifications even for zero values?

Tags: git, diff, diffstat

I'm doing a `diffstat` on my merge to see how many inserts, deletes *and* modifications I made like so:

```
git show 526162eed6 --first-parent --unified=0 | diffstat -m
```

This lists all the files and gives a summary at the end:

```
a/b/c | 10 ++++++++++
a/b/d |  5 +++++
...
10 files changed, 50 insertions(+), 10 modification(!)
```

However, I'd like to see *all* values even if they were zero:

```
10 files changed, 50 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-), 10 modifications(!)
```

How can I do this? The current workaround I have is to output a CSV via `... | diffstat -mt` and manually add up the columns via `awk`. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Not an answer, because it suffers the same "problem", but why pipe to an external program and not simply run `git diff --stat` (or `git show --stat`)? There's also `--short-stat`

Comment: @knittl: That doesn’t give you modifications AFAIK. Only insertions and deletions. Hence `diffstat`. Unless there’s a flag that you know can help?

Comment: I see. The modification metric is a heuristic, I wouldn't rely too much on it. The diff output only contains insertions (+) and deletions (-) (but that's not your question :))

Comment: I agree. It’s a good approximation though that can serve as a lower bound to capture the notion of a modification not too far from the truth.

Comment: btw, you know about the `--stat` option on anything that uses git's diff core? `git show --stat`? Still leaves you with the same problem and all, just easier to get there.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an option to do what you want. `diffstat` is a tool producing human readable output, not intended for machine consumption.

If you absolutely must parse/massage its output, you could use a very dirty hack (not recommended, can break anytime). Define shell functions:

```
stats() {
  read -r stat
  echo "$stat" | grep -o '[0-9]\+ file' | grep -o '[0-9]\+' || echo '0'
  echo 'files changed,' # does not match original output for 1 file
  echo "$stat" | grep -o '[0-9]\+ ins' | grep -o '[0-9]\+' || echo '0'
  echo 'insertions(+),'
  echo "$stat" | grep -o '[0-9]\+ del' | grep -o '[0-9]\+' || echo '0'
  echo 'deletions(-),'
  echo "$stat" | grep -o '[0-9]\+ mod' | grep -o '[0-9]\+' || echo '0'
  echo 'modifications(!)'
}
diffstats() {
  diffstat -sm | stats | paste -sd ' '
}
```

and then:

```
git diff | diffstats
```

Comment: This is close to what I was thinking. Given the brittleness I suggested the CSV/awk tabulation _hack_. That may be much less brittle.

Comment: @PhD parsing the CSV and manually summing the numbers is probably the best option then. My solution probably isn't even simpler than using awk to sum 4 columns